# Perl Replacing digits with "x" in string, but only in one particular location

Tags: regex, perl

I am parsing a log file filled with various errors. These are web errors, and it means that a client made a goof in formatting the date for our website. The log looks like this:

```
Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [17/12/2014]
Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [19/12/2014]
Error 123: Customer 1: Bad Date [123/23/222]
Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [null]
Error 123: Customer 6: Bad Date [12/14:]
Error 123: Customer 6: Bad Date [12/16:]
```

Now, the first two are really the same error for the same customer. Both lines, the date was reported as `DD/MM/YYYY` instead of `YYYY/MM/DD`, so I don't need to report this error twice. The last two lines are also the same error for the same customer. The used `MM/DD` and left off the year. The `null` date is another error even though I reported Customer #2's *Bad Date* error before. Somewhere, they're passing a null date.

What I'd like to do is compare the lines this way:

```
Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [xx/xx/xxxx]
Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [xx/xx/xxxx]
Error 123: Customer 1: Bad Date [xxx/xx/xxx]
Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [null]
Error 123: Customer 6: Bad Date [xx/xx:]
Error 123: Customer 6: Bad Date [xx/xx:]
```

Now, it's easy to see that the first two and last two lines are really the same error. The question is how to do this with a regular expression. I want to change all digits between the `[` and `]` to `x`, but I don't want to touch the rest of the string, so I don't want to convert the Error or Customer numbers to `x`.

I first tried:

```
$error =~ s/(\[.*?)\d/$1x/g;
```

But that only touches the first digit in the brackets. I've tried it without the non-greedy qualifier, but that only touches the last character.

I could simply do this:

```
$error =~ s/\d/x/g;
```

But that replaces all occurrences of a digit with an `x` destroying my Error number and Customer number.

I can pass the error line over and over again until there's no more replacement:

```
while ( my $error = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $error;
    while ( $error =~ s/(\[.*?)\d/$1x/ ) {
        1;
    }
    say qq(Error: "$error");
}
```

But there must be a way I can do this without having to loop through a `while` loop multiple times.

Is there a way to efficiently replace all occurrences of a digit with an `x`, but only between the two square brackets?

Comment: Actually I'm not ignoring it. I'm going to give the customer one example of the error where the date was `[21-10-2013]`, so I won't report a date of `[24-02-2013]` too. These are _probably_ from the same error. However, there's probably another error in the customer's site if a date of  `[12-10:]` is also reported. I want to report that one to the customer, but not if there's also a `[08-13:]`. The idea is to present an example of each date error type. That's why I need the `[...]` format, but not the actual numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use this solution:

```
$error =~ s{(\[ [^\]]+ \])}{
  (my $date = $1) =~ tr/0-9/x/;
  $date;
}ex;
```

<del>This won't work in older perls without a re-entrant regex engine.</del> Apparently, I was wrong. I tried that code with a freshly-[brewed](http://perlbrew.pl/) perl 5.10.1, and it worked just fine.

Alternatively, you could abuse an lvalue `substr`:

```
if ($error =~ /\[/gc) {
  my $start  = pos $error;
  my $length = index($error, ']', $start) - $start;
  substr($error, $start, $length) =~ tr/0-9/x/;
}
```

Comment: How new does Perl need to be to handle this?

Comment: I think you could use regex in the replacement expression before that, just not in `(?{...})` and `(??{...})`

Comment: @ikegami It seems you've been right about this, and it works just fine on older perls.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I was mistaken, this works just fine on older perls.

Comment: Also, you could use `tr/0-9/x/` instead of `s/[0-9]/x/g`; both will work, but the `tr///` will be slightly more efficient.

Comment: That's what I get for learning Perl back in the 3.x days. I never knew you could substitute a command in a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it all in one pass. You need to extract the part to which you want to do the replacements, apply the replacements, then reform the string.

```
if (
   my ($pre, $date, $post) =
      /^ ( [^\[\]]* \[ )( [^\[\]]* )( \] .* )/x
) {
   $date =~ s/[0-9]/x/g;
   $_ = "$pre$date$post";
}
```

This can be done more concisely.

```
s{ ( \[ [^\[\]]* \] ) }
 { ( my $x = $1 ) =~ s{[0-9]}{x}g; $x }xeg;
```

Or if you have 5.14,

```
s{ ( \[ [^\[\]]* \] ) }
 { $1 =~ s{[0-9]}{x}rg }xeg;
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like to break these problems up into much simpler pieces:

```
sub xdigit
{
    my $str= shift ;
    $str =~ tr/[0-9]/xxxxxxxxxx/ ;
    "[$str]"
}

my $x= 'Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [17/12/2014]' ;
$x =~ s/\[(.*?)\]/xdigit($1)/e ;
```

Outputs:

> Error 123: Customer 2: Bad Date [xx/xx/xxxx]

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$error =~ / \[ /gx;
$error =~ s/ \G (.*?) [0-9] /$1x/gx;
```

The search operation with the modifier `/g` initially positions the anchor (i.e. the start point for the next search) behind the matched string. The substitution operation then searches from this point (`\G`) and replaces the first digit somewhere behind it. Due to the `/g`, additionally the anchor is moved behind the substituted digit *and* search + substitution are repeated until the end of the string (or, with `([^]]*?)` instead of `(.*?)`, until the first closing bracket).

In your first try, the bracket is found only once; the first substitution moves the anchor behind the substituted digit, and the next search fails to find the bracket. With `use re 'debug';` to see the anchor moving.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($error =~ s/([\[\/x])\d/$1x/){};print
```